# Why i am getting the Id instead of Text from dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My home controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<District> allDistrict = new List<District>();
    List<Tehsil> allTehsil = new List<Tehsil>();
    List<SubTehsil> allSubTehsil = new List<SubTehsil>();
    using (FarmerBDContext db = new FarmerBDContext())
    {
        allDistrict = db.Districts.ToList();
    }
    ViewBag.DistrictId = new SelectList(allDistrict, "DistrictId", "DistrictName");
    ViewBag.TehsilId = new SelectList(allTehsil, "TehsilId", "Tehsilname");
    ViewBag.SubTehsilId = new SelectList(allSubTehsil, "SubTehsilId", "SubTehsilName");
    return View();
}
```

My District, Tehsil and SubTehsil dropdown are getting populated from another Model class.

***District Class***

```
public int DistrictId { get; set; }
public string DistrictName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tehsil> tbTehsils { get; set; }
```

My Tehsil And Subtehsil class are similar but have relationships b/w them

This model class is strongly typed to my form Index.cshtml

```
public string DistrictName { get; set; }
public string TehsilName { get; set; }
public string SubTehsilName { get; set; }
.... // Other Fields
```

And my Index view is like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-label Label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DistrictName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownList("DistrictName", (SelectList)@ViewBag.DistrictId, " -- Select District -- ", new { @class = "ddl"})
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DistrictName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="editor-label Label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TehsilName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TehsilName, @ViewBag.TehsilId as SelectList, "Select Tehsil", new { @class = "ddl" })
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TehsilName)
        </td>
    </tr>
    ....
</table>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Details" />
</p>
```

I am accessing them in another controller like this which is based on my model properties.

```
ViewBag.DistrictName = model.DistrictName;
ViewBag.TehsilName = model.TehsilName;
ViewBag.SubTehsilName = model.SubTehsilName;
```

I also tried accessing text of dropdown using the name of dropdownlist

```
Request.Form["DistrictName"].ToString()
```

and even used

```
FormCollection form
```

One more thing to note is that when i use simple

```
<select>
<option id=1>Abc</option>
</select>
```

I am getting the Text which is Abc

Comment: Show the code for the POST action that you are calling.

Comment: Please only include the code relevant to your question. Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Stephen i keep that in mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a `<select>` tag posts back the `value` attribute of its selected option. You usage of

```
ViewBag.DistrictId = new SelectList(allDistrict, "DistrictId", "DistrictName");
```

means that your generating options which have a `value` attribute equal to the `DistrictId` property of `District`. If you inspect the html your generating you will see (assuming you collection contains `new District() { DistrictId = 1, DistrictName = "ABC" };` and `new District() { DistrictId = 2, DistrictName = "XYZ" };`)

```
<select name="DistrictName" ...>
  <option value="1">ABC</option>
  <option value="2">XYZ</option>
</select>
```

If you want the value of the `DistrictName` property to be bound to your model, then it needs to be

```
ViewBag.DistrictId = new SelectList(allDistrict, "DistrictName", "DistrictName");
```

Alternatively you could do

```
IEnumerable<string> allDistrict = db.Districts.Select(d => d.DistrictName);
ViewBag.DistrictId = new SelectList(allDistrict); // a more appropriate name might be ViewBag.DistrictList
```

Side note: html table elements are for tabular data, not layout!

Comment: Then stick with your original code which adds the `ID` as the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem` but change your property to `public int DistrictName { get; set; }` - Why are you asking to return the `Name` when in fact you do want the `ID` as you already have? (and if they are cascading, the 2nd  and  3rd `SelectList`'s should be `new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());`

Comment: I am displaying the Form on next page so i want to show the text field

Comment: Sorry, don't understand you comment. My answer is correct for this question. If you have a new question, then ask a new question explaining what your trying to do and showing the relevant code.

Comment: And did you still need an answer for [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490447/what-should-i-pass-from-the-controller-to-my-view-in-asp-net-mvc-4-with-entity-f)?